# django tastypie only fetch a particular field of a particular object

Tags: django, json, tastypie

In tastypie my url: /api/v1/course/1/?format=json gives the following json:

```
{
created_on: "2012-02-27T08:00:54",
description: "this is course 1",
id: "1",
resource_uri: "/api/v1/course/1/",
subjects: [
    "/api/v1/subject/1/",
    "/api/v1/subject/2/"
],
title: "Course 1"
}
```

I want to do something like:

```
/api/v1/course/1/subjects/?format=json
```

to get only the list of subjects for a given course. Is this possible?

Comment: as json services does not require SEO I don't get the point. Or maybe you want all subjects related to you course.

Comment: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

Comment: yes, I just was wondering if in a more complicated nested json, can i just query for the entity I want. I just want the subjects, if possible. In reality this json is too big and I was thinking if there is a way to do this without writing a new resource.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to do something like [this](http://blog.apigee.com/detail/restful_api_design_can_your_api_give_developers_just_the_information/) where you specify a `fields` parameter so users can request only the fields they want. In your case, a user would send the request

```
/api/v1/course/1/?format=json&fields=subjects
```

One way to implement this is to extend Tastypie to give you this functionality. Currently, the [full_dehydrate](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L648) method iterates over all fields and dehydrates each of them. You can add in a check to see if the user entered `fields` and if so, just skip the dehydrate phase for any fields that were not specified.

Comment: Here is an extension that does just that: https://github.com/dan-klasson/django-tastypie-specified-fields. Although it does not yet support m2m.

Answer (score 0):

The reverse relations are not created by default in tastypie but it looks pretty simple:

http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#reverse-relationships

```
class CourseResource(ModelResource):
    subjects = fields.ToManyField('myapp.api.resources.SubjectResource', 'subjects', full=True)
    class Meta:
        queryset = Course.objects.all()

class SubjectResource(ModelResource):
    course = fields.ToOneField(CourseResource, 'courses')

    class Meta:
        queryset = Subject.objects.all()
```

Comment: No, I have done this exact same thing which shows subjects within the course json, as per the json posted in the question. I was wondering if I can just get the subjects only, or does my question not make sense? thanks.

Comment: I added full=True, it's no more links but full objects... was it what you wanted? I'm discovering tastypie with you to answer so please be indulgent ^^.

Comment: you still may do 2 course ressource to have one with only subjects our have a subject ressource with a custom query_filter http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#advanced-filtering

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
I then implemented a very simple django-tastypie extension called [django-tastypie-specific-fields](https://github.com/KevinJio/django-tastypie-specific-fields) which will help you to select the fields you are interested in. You will able to fetch your data with such a simple request

```
/api/v1/course/1/?format=json&fields=subjects
```

It will also give you much more possibilities.